# How to draw connection between drawitems?

Tags: drawing, smartgwt, relationships, drawimage, connector

I want to develop a workflow Tool with smartgwt. My problem is to draw relationships between drawitems. I tried libary gwt-connectors, but its not working on canvas,only on AbsolutePanels. Can anybody help me? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since AbsolutePanel implements the interface IsWidget it should be no Problem to embedd a AbsolutePanel into a SmartGWT Canvas.

For Example:

```
AbsolutePanel boundaryPanel = new AbsolutePanel();
//draw diagram into baundaryPanel...
Canvas wrapper = new HLayout();
wrapper.addChild(boundaryPanel.asWidget());
```

Comment: that is also not working...i found out,, that i only can connect HTML, Image or Label-Widgets with gwt-connectors :(

Comment: Ok, than I would recommend you to use another library. For instance I used gwt-links which is a very impressive library for such a usecase. Espacially for your workflow tool this library could be a good match.

Comment: Ok thanks! Are there any showcases? Or do you have an example how to draw connection with this libary?

Comment: Unhappily the showcase seems to be broken.
But there is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sd9Hw83x5lg) that  shows a single example of the showcase. When you want to get started with that library you could use the [gwt-links-wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-links/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki).

Comment: thats exactly what i need! i will try that :)

Comment: Which widgets do you want to resize?

Comment: Ich want to resize images:)

Comment: For example you could wrap the image into a Layout and [let a user resize this HLayout](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_user_sizing).

Comment: that works now, thank you! one last question...how can the user draw connection between two hlayouts?

Comment: A user could connect widgets after they are added to the DiagramController

Comment: hmm...i can resize and drag the images (hlayout with image as background) around, but there are no knobs shown to connect them, like in the video. what could be wrong?

Comment: Preferably you could compare your solution with the [source code of the examples](https://github.com/prenaudin/gwt-links/tree/master/gwt-links-parent/gwt-links-demo/src/main/java/com/orange/links/demo/client/example)